# Objective-C .h files vs .m files

Tags: objective-c, interface

I understand why you seperste a class into a header file and a implementation file. However i do not understand why when you then create a program to use that code, you import the header file again? I would think you would import the .m file, as that is where the class definitions are, otherwise your program simply knows the names of the class/methods, but not what to do with them, or how to use them. I need either a relatively detailed answer for this, or someone pointing me in the direction to find one.

Comment: All compiled languages work differently than scripted languages. While scripted languages include the working code everywhere they need it, compiled languages only include the prototypes that use those functions. The linker is responsible for doing the connections

Comment: @achi You are talking nonsense, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of header files as a sort of promise.  You don't know when or in what order the compiler will actually generate the machine readable code for a given class, but the header file will ensure that the compiler knows, in any file in which it is included, that eventually that code *will* exist in machine readable form.

Comment: This is "sort of promise" is called a *declaration*.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a derivative of C.

Traditionally, C (also ObjC) compilers can process one source file(.c or .m) at a time (it is called translation unit). Importing (or including) is just a preprocessing step that is not different than appending the whole content of the included file into the including source file.

After compiling is done, all the compiled source files (object files) are linked together into a single output file.

You can #include/#import any file (source code, text, html anything) in any source files at any place.

After compiling is done, all the compiled source files (object files) are linked together into a single output file.

Suppose, someone include A.m in B.m and then compile and link both files? He'll have two copies of A.m's code. Of course linking will fail.